# Removing one type of highlighting in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting, code, intellij-idea

How to remove this type of highlighting in Intellij Idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`File -> Settings -> Inspectins` and disable `Unchecked warning` checkbox.

[image]

Or you may just use `@SuppressWarnings(“unchecked”)` annotation to [suppress unchecked warnings](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-suppress-unchecked-warnings-java/) in Java.